# Where is the verb-object collocation error in 老板很赏识李朝阳温文尔雅的风度和丰富的知识，对他十分器重?

Tags: grammar, verbs

This is a 语病 question from HSK6 Standard Course (p.93 [photo of original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbf29.jpg)):

> 老板很赏识李朝阳温文尔雅的风度和丰富的知识，对他十分器重。

The corrections are:

> 动词和宾语搭配不当。
> **李朝阳有着温文尔雅的风度和丰富的知识，老板很赏识他**，对他十分器重。

There is only one verb here (the other verb 器重 is unmodified), namely:

> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E8%B5%8F%E8%AF%86) 赏识 (shǎng​shí​): to appreciate / to recognize the worth of sth / appreciation

And the correction changes the object of 赏识 from 风度和知识 (ignoring the attributives) to 他.  At first I thought maybe it's only possible to 赏识 a person, but I found examples like the following online:

> 此时，业务团队将开始赏识您的智慧。 ([YouDao](https://youdao.com/result?word=lj%3A%E8%B5%8F%E8%AF%86&lang=en))
> 他赏识保罗的勤奋。  ([Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E8%B5%8F%E8%AF%86))

So I don't see any reason why 风度 nor 知识 cannot be 赏识ed.

**Question**: Where is the verb-object collocation error in the 语病 sentence?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you that "I don't see any reason why 风度 or 知识 cannot be 赏识ed."

The following examples are very common usage of 赏识.

他是队长特别赏识的一个队员。He is a member whom the team leader particularly appreciates.

她赏识他的才华，而不是他的外表。She appreciated his talent, not his appearance.

她并不赏识他那种耍小聪明的表演。She didn't appreciate his cleverness.

Comment: I disagree with the second and third examples, 赏识才华 and 赏识表演 have the wrong objects, the object in the first sentence is 队员(a human)

Comment: The object for the 2nd sentence is "他的才华", for the third is "他那种耍小聪明的表演".

Comment: I agree that, in the 2nd and 3rd sentences, using 欣赏 may be better. But people use 赏识 quite often.

Answer (score 1):

> 老板很[赏识]李朝阳温文尔雅的风度和丰富的[知识]，对他十分器重。

Emotion Verbs like 赏识(look highly upon) and 妒忌(jealous) can only be applied to a human object

The valid object for the verb 赏识 is not 李朝阳的知识 (李朝阳's Knowledge) but himself. You can rephrase this sentence many different ways as long as the object is a 李朝阳, that sentence would be correct

Similarly, a sentence like "他很[妒忌]我的[才能] (He is jealous of my talent)" might look normal at first, but when you break it down and match 妒忌(v) with 才能(object), it is also a sick sentence

The correct phrasing is "因為我有才能，他很[妒忌][我]"

OP found:

> 此时，业务团队将开始[赏识]您的[智慧]。 (YouDao); 他[赏识]保罗的[勤奋]。 (Jukuu)

The above two examples are similar to my example. Both sentences seem fine if you don't notice the fact that the objects were not humans

Comment: If you search "欣賞 藝賞品", you'd find many examples in which 欣賞 is applied to arts.

Comment: in 欣賞 藝賞品 (enjoy art,), 欣賞 is an action verb,  In 欣賞我 (admire me), 欣賞 is an emotion verb, To avoid confusion, I changed  it to 妒忌 in my example